# Datetime picker con fecha y hora en asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, mvc, datepicker, jquery-datepicker, datetimepicker

NECESITO AYUDA PARA AGREGAR UN CAMPO QUE ME RECOJA LA FECHA Y HORA EN ASP.NET MVC

ESTE ES EL CODIGO HTML DE LA VISTA

```
 <div class="form-group">
                 
                    <strong>Fecha de Analisis</strong>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha_analisis, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha_analisis, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                </div>
```

ESTE ES EL CODIGO JAVASCRIPT

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {

            $(".datepicker").datepicker({

                controlType: "select",
                oneLine: true,
                timeFormat: "HH:mm"
    });
});

    </script>



}
```

AL FINAL SOLO ME CARGA EL DISEÑO PARA AGREGAR LA FECHA Y LA HORA NO ME SALE

[image: imagen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desconozco si es requerido usar el datetimepicker js, pero si no, no te basta un `input type="datetime-local"/>`? así se implementaría en tu código:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                 
                    <strong>Fecha de Analisis</strong>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha_analisis, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker", @type="datetime-local" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha_analisis, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                </div>
```

Comment: Eres un angel enviado por Dios, gracias a ti pude resolver ese error que me tenia horas preocupada :)

Comment: no es nada, un placer :D